# How to get reference to a specific plot space in Core Plot

Tags: plot, core-plot, space

How do I get reference to a plot space?
In case there is only one plot space, we can use the following code to create and get reference to the default plot space:

```
CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace
```

So we can add plot to this plot space afterwards. The trouble comes when there is more than one plot space in the graph, and we try to add plot to a non-default plot space from another method (that is, the relevant plot space was created in another method). There should be something about array of plot spaces, but I can't get it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options:

- Set the `identifier` for the new plot space and use `-plotSpaceWithIdentifier:` to retrieve a reference from the graph.
- Use `-plotSpaceAtIndex:` to refer to plot spaces in the order they were added to the graph. The default plot space is at index 0.
- Keep a reference to each new plot space elsewhere in your app (for example, in an instance variable).

Comment: Thanks my friend. I chose the second option, but slightly different because I don't know how to use '-plotSpaceAtIndex:'. So, I use '[[graph allPlotSpaces] objectAtIndex:index]'. It seems to be producing the result I expect.